# Displaying JSON content to HTML

Tags: html, json

Can you guys tell me how the text which i want to display doest appear in html ? will be glad if you can help me, here is code.

```
*<script>
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "RoadBikes-Michał_Nowakowski.json";

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        myFunction(myArr);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

                function myFunction(arr) {
                    var out = "";
                    var i;
                    console.log(arr.RoadBikes.bike);
                    for(i = 0; i < arr.RoadBikes.bike.length; i++) {
                        out +=  "<li><ul>" + 
                        "<li>Nazwa: " +  arr.RoadBikes.bike[i].brand.name1 "</li>"+
                        "</ul></li>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("tak").innerHTML = out;
                }
            </script>
```

*here is my [json document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cetcr.png) i want to display only RoadBikes->bike->brand->name1

Comment: Why do you only address the guys and not the ladies among us?

Comment: Please refrain from inserting pictures or screenshots of text documents into your question, just copy/paste the `json` text content directly into your question as you did with the `javascript` portion so we may be able to reproduce your code.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your script near `</li>`. Did you check the console?

Comment: Where exactly ?

Comment: any1 any solutions ?

Comment: I think they mean a `+` is missing to concatenate the strings between ..`brand.name1` and `"</li>"`

Comment: thanks m8 :) now new problem occurs : locally works but on server it doesnt :D